# How to manually call for change detection in all sub components?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular2-changedetection

I am developing a web application using angular dart.

I have a component A which has 'n' number of component B's in its template.

Component A provides data for Component B by input binding.

Component A handles posting to API and getting from API.

Whenever the data changes in component A, it should update in component B.

But I don't see that happening.

I used ngOnChanges and ngAfterChanges in component B but it was not getting called when the data in component A changes.

There are many B components(say 800) so I cannot manually call change detection in each component whenever data changes in A.

What should I do to automatically update the data in component B whenever data in A changes?

component_a.html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let nameMap of maps">
   <component_b [nameMap]="nameMap">
   </component_b>
</ng-container>
```

component_b.dart:

```
class ComponentB {
  @Input()
  Map<int, String> nameMap;
}
```

Suppose a value in nameMap's item has changed in ComponentA. How to reflect it in ComponentB?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

So the way that angular works is that it uses identity to tell when a binding changes. So in this case if the map instance is not changing it is not going to know to update itself.

There is no way for a parent to invalidate the tree below, there is a way for a child to invalidate a tree above FWIW that is what markForCheck does.

There is a couple of ways you could get this to work:

- Create a new map for the instances when the data changes (this
  would be my suggestion)
- Use ObservableMap and listen for updates
  on the map and call markForCheck in ComponentB and make it OnPush

Comment: Thanks. The use case is this: Component B (child) calls a callback method provided by Component A (parent) to get a thing done. What I did to solve the problem was pass the component instance (B) to A in the callback and then called a method in the child component(B) from parent(A) after the map in A was updated. This method in child actually reads the map in B that was updated and updates the local variables in B that are dependent on the map. Is this wrong?

Comment: I would probably just create a new instance of the map and let change detection call the input on B and then update the local variables there. You need a new instance of the map to get the input to be set again.

Comment: "...and let change detection call the input on B and then update the local variables there..." - how to do this? I implemented ngOnChanges() and ngAfterChanges() but it was not getting called.

Comment: You need a brand new object for the Map that is passed into ComponentB